# Overlapping Total Live Duration Calculation

Tags: vba, excel

Am trying to calculate the total duration of Equipment Live Time.
In the case of the Equipment has only one serves then there is no overlap between Live Time events. 
The issue with the orders that have Equipment with mulibel services Each one can overlap with multiple other Time.

[image: Example]

I need to calculate the total amount of time any each Equipment ID then retain the calculation in Eq. LIVE Time.
I'm new in programming and I couldn't find a solution for that.
Please support

```
Sub Cul_Eq_Live_Time()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 Dim n As Long, lr_LT As Integer, lr_data As Integer
 Dim z As Integer, y As Integer, x As Integer, EqID As String, iLoop As Integer, No_CCTs As Integer

 Dim xDate As Date, yDate As Date, aDate As Date, bData As Date, iDate As Date, eDate As Date, Diff As Integer, EqLiveT As Long, T As Integer, tRange As Range
 Dim nDate As Date, dDate As Date


  lr_LT = Sheets("Live Time").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'initial cell in Tuning sheet & range

  T = 2
  Set tRange = Sheets("Tuning").Range("B2:C2000")

'loop all orders

 For n = 3 To lr_LT

 'get new EqID
EqID = Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "E").Value
' find if the cuont EqID is 1 then live time will be the same of the CCT live time.
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Live Time").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, 5).Value)
If y <= 1 Then
Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "P").Value = Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "K").Value
GoTo End_n_Loop

End If
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' in the cae of Eq. more the one orders
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' if live time alredy culculated
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Tuning").Range("B:B"), Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "E").Value) >= 1 Then
Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "P").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(EqID, tRange, 2, False)
GoTo End_n_Loop
End If
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' in the caee of above condition not found

'get iDate & eDate

iDate = Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "H").Value
eDate = Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "I").Value
Diff = 0
EqLiveT = 0
No_CCTs = 1
xDate = iDate
yDate = eDate


If eDate = 0 Then
eDate = Date
End If

' iLoop for the Eq. that have more the one orders

For iLoop = n + 1 To lr_LT

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

If Sheets("Live Time").Cells(iLoop, "H").Value <> EqID Then
GoTo End_iLoop
End If

' count the nomber of CCt for this Eq.

No_CCTs = No_CCTs + 1

' in the case of the CCT live eDate = today
If Sheets("Live Time").Cells(iLoop, "I").Value = 0 Then
dDate = Date
End If

' update the dates

aDate = Sheets("Live Time").Cells(iLoop, "H").Value
bDate = Sheets("Live Time").Cells(iLoop, "I").Value

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''''''' x<-------->y


''''''''' a<-------->b

If xDate >= aDate And xDate < bDate And yDate >= bDate Then

nDate = aDate
dDate = yDate
GoTo End_iLoop

End If

''''''''''''''' x<-------->y


''''''''''''''''''' a<-------->b
If CDate(xDate) < CDate(aDate) And CDate(yDate) > CDate(aDate) And CDate(yDate) <= CDate(bDate) Then

nDate = xDate
dDate = bDate
GoTo End_iLoop

End If

''''''''''''''' x<-------->y


''''''''''' a<---------------->b
If xDate > aDate And xDate < bDate And yDate >= aDate And yDate <= bDate Then
nDate = aDate
dDate = bDate
GoTo End_iLoop

End If

''''''' x<------------------>y


''''''''''' a<----------->b
If xDate < aDate And yDate > bDate And aDate > yDate Then
nDate = xDate
dDate = yDate
GoTo End_iLoop

End If

''''''' x<------------------>y ''''''''''' a<----------->b
If yDate > aDate And xDate > aDate And bDate > yDate Then
nDate = xDate
dDate = yDate
Diff = Diff + (aDate - yDate)
GoTo End_iLoop
End If

End_iLoop:

Next iLoop

'AfterLoop

EqLiveT = nDate - dDate - Diff

'EqLiveT = EqLiveT - Diff

Sheets("Live Time").Cells(n, "P").Value = EqLiveT
Sheets("Tuning").Cells(T, "A").Value = T - 1
Sheets("Tuning").Cells(T, "B").Value = EqID
Sheets("Tuning").Cells(T, "C").Value = EqLiveT
Sheets("Tuning").Cells(T, "D").Value = No_CCTs
T = T + 1

End_n_Loop:

Next n

MsgBox "Done"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, your code is quite long and hard to read. To get a good answer you should ask a **technical** question here. Asking for support **is not asking a question**: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and [ask]. At least give an example data set, a good explanation how you would calculate that by hand and what the expected result would be.

Comment: As comment above says - too long and too complex. The first thing you need to do is to create a function that breaks out the overlap logic and returns a value you can use in your calculation. I would imagine that you have two date spans as input and number of overlapping days as output. Using this, you can accumulate the spans and subtract the overlaps.

Comment: as I have mentioned, I'm really new to programming. Hawver, my issue in the calculation the total live duration in the case of overlapping.

Comment: @MohammedZiara we cannot tell you how to calculate something or how your algorithm should look like. This is what you should tell us and then we can help you with the technical / coding part, but for now it is even unclear what you are trying to calculate. We don't know what to do to calculate the "*total live duration*" if you don't tell us how this is calculated. You still didn't add the requested example in your question: "*At least give an example data set, a good explanation how you would calculate that by hand and what the expected result would be.*"

Comment: @MohammedZiara In other words, if you don't know how to calculate it by hand with a calculator, then you cannot calculate it with Excel. Excel is only as smart as you, it cannot do any magical things. You need to tell us how this is calculated by hand first. Then we can help you to find out to tell Excel how to do it.